# Upload to OneDrive returning 504 Gateway Timeout (Unknown error )

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to upload new file to the OneDrive using Microsoft.GrapApi after that modify it. Frequenlty I am getting the error `504 Gateway Timeout (Unknown error )` during upload modified file.

[Here](https://github.com/kustic13/MSGraphOneDriveIssue) you can find sample of azure function which frequenlty throws `504 Gateway Timeout (Unknown error )` error. In order to get the error you need to call azure function end-point many times by using script from repo.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the size of the file you are trying to upload, [according to Microsoft Graph the limit for "simple" uploads is 4MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs), you will have to [create an upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0), chunk the file in bytes and send them in multiple requests.

Comment: I catch this error using very small file exactly less then 4MB. You can try by own, I have shared the repo with sample.