# Microsoft Graph OneDrive API return 504 Gateway timeout when uploading file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph OneDrive API to upload a file, it works before until recently. Microsoft API server return "504 Gateway Timeout". Any idea?

```php
$tokenCache = new \App\TokenStore\TokenCache;
$accessToken = $tokenCache->getClientCredentialsAccessToken();

$graph = new \Microsoft\Graph\Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

$requestUrl = "/drives/{drive-id}/items/root:/files/2019/466/466-1566268336-oYgN-subway.csv:/content";

$localPath = "/var/www/html/laravel/public/attachments/466/a3Gc9Yx0ekNzC4zIxeGyvClEJrtXGFwDJIoS0FlM/466-1566268583-PvTZ-subway.csv";

$result = $graph->createRequest('PUT', $requestUrl)
          ->upload($localPath);

dd($result);
```

```
Server error: `PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/items/root:/files/2019/466/466-1566268336-oYgN-subway.csv:/content` resulted in a `504 Gateway Timeout` response
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload to OneDrive returning 504 Gateway Timeout (Unknown error )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580263/upload-to-onedrive-returning-504-gateway-timeout-unknown-error)